# Weakly connected Graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

From [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29):

> "A directed graph is called weakly connected if replacing all of its directed edges with undirected edges produces a connected (undirected) graph"

Is this accurate?

[image]

The above graph is connected when all directed edges are replaced with undirected edges.But there is no path between B to D or D to B which violates the weakly typed property..Am i right?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't correct? It's entirely possible that Wikipedia is wrong, but you at least need some evidence showing otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's the definition that seems to be used most places. Another wording of it from some [graph search documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphconncomp.html),

> A weakly connected component is a maximal group of nodes that are mutually reachable by violating the edge directions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [directed graph page in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph):

> A digraph G is called weakly connected (or just connected[4]) if the undirected underlying graph obtained by replacing all directed edges of G with undirected edges is a connected graph. A digraph is strongly connected or strong if it contains a directed path from u to v and a directed path from v to u for every pair of vertices u,v. The strong components are the maximal strongly connected subgraphs.

Therefore, yes - the definition is correct. It may be worth noting that a graph may be both strongly and weakly connected.